# insert into in access shows error

Tags: database, vba, ms-access

```
Call connectDB
    sql = ""
    sql = sql & "INSERT INTO cust([Client Name],[Mobile No],[Address],[City],[State],[Pincode],[Email],[Category],[Contact Name],"
   sql = sql & "[Enquiry],[ActiveFlag])" & vbCrLf


                       sql = sql & " VALUES (" & vbCrLf
                        sql = sql & "'" & txtClientName.Text & "'," & vbCrLf
                        sql = sql & "'" & txtMobile.Text & "'," & vbCrLf
                        sql = sql & "'" & txtAddress.Text & "'," & vbCrLf
                        sql = sql & "" & txtcity.Text & "," & vbCrLf
                        sql = sql & "'" & txtState.Text & "'," & vbCrLf
                        sql = sql & "'" & txtPIN.Text & "'," & vbCrLf
                        sql = sql & "'" & txtEmail.Text & "'," & vbCrLf
                        sql = sql & "'" & cmbCatagory.Value & "'," & vbCrLf
                        sql = sql & "'" & txtContactPerson.Text & "')" & vbCrLf
                        sql = sql & "'Y','Y');"


                        cn.Execute sql
```

it shows error like one are more values not given.. but i give all the values and also it gives

> need Semicolon (;) in end of the SQL statement

Comment: (a) Is [City] a text field or a numeric field?  If it is text, why don't you put quotation marks around its value?  (b) Why do you put a `)` between the value for [Contact Name] and the value for [Enquiry] rather than putting a `,` there?

Comment: Just wondering: why do you add `& vbCrLf` at the end of each line? The sql doesn't need it and your code looks a lot cleaner without it.

Comment: Also, `txtAddress.Text` etc. must be `txtAddress.Value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Call connectDB
    sql = ""
    sql = sql & "INSERT INTO cust([Client Name],[Mobile No],[Address],[City],[State],[Pincode],[Email],[Category],[Contact Name],"
   sql = sql & "[Enquiry],[ActiveFlag])" & vbCrLf


                       sql = sql & " VALUES (" & vbCrLf
                        sql = sql & "'" & txtClientName.Text & "'," & vbCrLf
                        sql = sql & "'" & txtMobile.Text & "'," & vbCrLf
                        sql = sql & "'" & txtAddress.Text & "'," & vbCrLf
                        sql = sql & "" & txtcity.Text & "," & vbCrLf
                        sql = sql & "'" & txtState.Text & "'," & vbCrLf
                        sql = sql & "'" & txtPIN.Text & "'," & vbCrLf
                        sql = sql & "'" & txtEmail.Text & "'," & vbCrLf
                        sql = sql & "'" & cmbCatagory.Value & "'," & vbCrLf
                        sql = sql & "'" & txtContactPerson.Text & "'," & vbCrLf
                        sql = sql & "'Y','Y');"


                        cn.Execute sql
```